# Java use capture of ? in generic class

Tags: java, generics

I have such a class

```
class MyClass<T extends AnotherClass> {}
```

and such a map

```
Map<Class<? extends MyClass>, MyClass<?>> map;
```

Now my ide gives me a warning which says "Raw use of parameterized class 'MyClass'", and if I change the signature of map to

```
Map<Class<? extends MyClass<?>>, MyClass<?>> map;
```

It gives a error when I try to put entry in the map using

```
MyClass<?> foo = ...;
map.put(foo.getClass(), foo);
```

and it says "Require type: Class< ? extends MyClass< ?>>, Provided: Class< capture of ? extends MyClass>
. If I can somehow use Class object as the map's key without creating warnings?

**updated**

The javadoc of getClass method says

> The actual result type is Class where |X| is the erasure of the static type of the expression on which getClass is called.

If it means that I can never get a Class< ? extends MyClass< ?>> object by getClass method, since the generic information of MyClass has been erasured?

**updated 2**

I would like to use the map like this

```
public <C extends MyClass<?>> C getMyInstance(Class<C> clazz) {
    return clazz.cast(map.get(clazz));
}
```

Comment: I think you need to always specify that `MyClass<>` has an `extends AnotherClass` in the angle brackets or it violates the first constraint.

Comment: Are you trying to do something like a [typesafe heterogeneous container?](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2861454&seqNum=8)

Comment: @erickson nearly that, but as you can see, in my case, the type of map value is a generic type, and its getClass method could only return a Class< ? extends MyClass> instance which causing a raw use warning. using a Map< Class< ?>, Object> is also ok for me, but I wonder if there are some way to writing the code with more bounding but without raw use warning.

Comment: @markspace thank you for your comment, but I can't get your point. could you please give me an example?

Comment: Don't use `?` for this.

Comment: What are you actually using this map for once you've put everything into it? Are you simply trying to store an instance for every `MyClass` subclass? Will you ever use the key for anything by itself?

Comment: @AndyTurner thank you for your comment, my usage of the map is updated in the question.

Comment: Is just silencing the warning an option? A well placed `@SuppressWarnings` should do it. The language is basically forcing your hand.

Comment: The problem you have is that you're trying to key a generic map by something which is fundamentally incompatible with generics. Do you have to use the class? Could you use some sort of `Key<C>` instead?

Comment: Your goal does not depend on a precise key type. Your code works without problems when you use `Map<Class<?>, MyClass<?>>`. In fact, even `Map<Object, MyClass<?>>` would work. You should ensure that the map is sufficiently encapsulated and the method containing the `put` call is as restrictive as needed.